# AWS DMS Start replication task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am able to create the DMS instances through through the YAML file. But I am not able to start the task to migrate the data. Is there any way I add the script in YAML to start the process automatically once the task gets created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the official white paper for this yes I have done migration to DynamoDB using replication task through YAML automatically.

Please follow this for help: https://github.com/aws-samples/specialty-practice-code-samples/tree/master/migrate-delimited-files-to-nosql

To start your Task start the migration you can use cloudformation even a A cloud watch event scheduler.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dms-replicationtask.html

And this one also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/create-replication-task.html

I followed these 3 document and migrated a giant DB to DynamoDB.

What I did is created a replication task and scheduled a cloud watch event on it and with help of Lambda function triggered that CloudFormation YAML to migrated the DB.